# How to export the last line generated by sum attributes?

Tags: javascript, odoo

In order to export a view to an excel file I use this but the problem is that I can't export the last line generated by sum attributes:

```
if (children) {
        // find only rows with data
        view.$el.find('.o_list_view > tbody > tr[data-id]:has(.o_list_record_selector input:checkbox:checked)')
        .each(function () {
            var $row = $(this);
            var export_row = [];
            $.each(export_columns_keys, function () {
                var $cell = $row.find('td[data-field="' + this + '"]')
                var $cellcheckbox = $cell.find('.o_checkbox input:checkbox');
                if ($cellcheckbox.length) {
                    export_row.push(
                        $cellcheckbox.is(":checked")
                        ? _t("True") : _t("False")
                    );
                }
                else {
                    var text = $cell.text().trim();
                        export_row.push(text);
                    }
                });
                export_rows.push(export_row);
            });
        }
```

how can I add it ? is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `var export_row = [];` be `var export_rows = [];` ? (Note the final s)

Comment: it's not the case. I solved it and it has no relation with var export_row = []